# Expresso Store - Custom Dimensions

Tags: expresso-store, product

I have a couple questions regarding Expresso Store:

- Is it possible to add custom dimensions to a product? Our client sells Sofas which have more than just Length/Width/Height (Overall Depth, Seat Width, Seat Height etc), so we need to be able to add new dimension fields.
- Is it possible to group variations? The customers need to be able to choose the materials and colours for the sofas, so we have multiple ranges of materials and colours available.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Exp-resso Store only extends ExpressionEngine, so you can add all the fields you want. If those attributes effect price or need to be part of a custom order, you would add them as attributes.

Again this can be done through ExpressionEngine for just showing content. If you need this to pass through as Attributes you can do so as well. You can create as many variation groups with options as you wish.

Comment: Is there anyway to extend the fieldtype with these new dimensions? I would ideally like the keep the main product details grouped together. Also, I see how variations work now, but is there anyway to add images to each variation option?